# How to filter Integer in DataView RowFilter using combobox and textbox?

Tags: c#, winforms, dataview, rowfilter

So, I have a comoboBox1 and textBox1

comboBox1 is set to the name of columns from dataview dv

and the textBox1 is for the search

So, I tried simple code something like this :

```
dv.RowFilter = "Convert([City Number], System.String) LIKE '%2%'";
```

and the code above works well

but then I tried to replace City Number and %2% with value from comboBox1 and textBox1,

into something like this.

```
dv.RowFilter = "Convert([comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()], System.String) LIKE '%{0}%'", textBox1.Text;
```

The syntax seems wrong, but you know what I mean.

So how to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`string.Format`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx) to make the filter expression this way:

```
var column = comboBox1.GetItemText(comboBox1.SelectedItem);
var value = textBox1.Text;
var filter = string.Format("Convert([{0}], System.String) LIKE '%{1}%'", column, value);
dv.RowFilter = filter;
```

Comment: Thank you, works like a charm. This probably the only filter using parameters as the values that I could find on internet,

Comment: Actually, this code filter column with datatype string, integer and date.
Pretty neat, huh?

Comment: This part `Convert([{0}], System.String)` converts any type to string and makes search more friendly for users. You can use the same logic to implement a simple full text search for your data which returns the result based on search in all columns. This way when the user enters a value, you can select all records which contains that value in any on columns.