# Whats is proper way of using RowFilter on DataGridView populated with DataTable?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, datatable

I have followed method from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13173915/search-for-value-in-datagridview-in-a-column) to perform search on datagridview

Below is my attempt. I would like to stop querying database with DgvSearch() method on text change, instead use RowFilter.

Within current attempt, datagridview is properly populated from LoadDataParts(), when i start typing in TxtPP_GBC2, i see only column header, no exception is thrown.

GBC column is defined as "INT".

**Expected result -> TxtPP_GBC2_TextChanged() will behave same like DgvSearch()**

```
public partial class ProgramPart : Form
{
    public SqlConnection Con { get; } = new SqlConnection(@"***");
    public  string UserDBO;
    private DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
    public ProgramPart()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LoadDataParts();
    }
    public void LoadDataParts()
    {
        string sql3 = "SELECT * FROM Parts";

        SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql3, Con);
        sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
        sqlDataAdapter.Dispose();
        dataGridView1n.DataSource = dataTable;
    }

    private void TxtPP_GBC2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //DgvSearch(); //////// DgvSearch() works perferctly
        try
        {
            if(txtPP_GBC2.Text == "")
            {
                dataTable.Clear();
                LoadDataParts();
                dataGridView1n.Refresh();
                return;
            }
            (dataGridView1n.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = "GBC = '" + Convert.ToInt32(txtPP_GBC2.Text) + "'";
            dataGridView1n.Refresh();
        }
        catch(Exception s)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(s.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void DgvSearch()
    {
        string sql3 = "SELECT * FROM Parts WHERE GBC LIKE @GBC2 AND Description LIKE @DES";
        Con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql3, Con);
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GBC2", SqlDbType.Int).Value = "%" + txtPP_GBC2.Text + "%";
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DES", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "%" + txtPP_Description2.Text + "%";

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "Parts");
        da.Dispose();
        dataGridView1n.DataSource = ds;
        dataGridView1n.DataMember = "Parts";
        Con.Close();


  }
}
```

Comment: If the column is int, why are you comparing it with an string? Maybe you are looking for something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40899054/3110834)?

Comment: Can You provide working example @RezaAghaei ?

Comment: Whoa; I'd urge you to reconsider- loading an entire database table full of parts into a local datatable it's so you can search them is a fairly terrible idea in all but the most artificially small data set examples. Databases are very good at searching data. C# datatables are comparatively very bad at searching. Dragging potentially millions of records over a network so they can be searched locally is an awful idea. Perhaps consider implanting a delay so you only run a search 1 second after the user stops typing, that way you don't do a search on every key press. (Called debouncing)

Comment: @CaiusJard - Thank You, what i understood. You suggested me to go back with querying SQL but implement delay between queries ?

Comment: Yep, that's what I'd recommend- either have the user press return etc to kick off a search or every time they press a key reset a counter to 0, increment it on a 100ms timer and only kick off a query when it reaches 10 etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Convert` expression function to convert value of the int column to the string and compare it using such filter:

```
private DataTable LoadData()
{
    var dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("C1", typeof(int));
    dt.Rows.Add(1);
    dt.Rows.Add(11);
    dt.Rows.Add(2);
    dt.Rows.Add(22);
    return dt;       
}
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.DataSource = LoadData();
}
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var filter = "";
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
        filter = $"Convert([C1], System.String) = '{textBox1.Text}'";
    (dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = filter;
}
```

If for any reason you prefer `LIKE` operator, you need to change the filter to:

```
filter = $"Convert([C1], System.String) LIKE '%{textBox1.Text}%'";
```

Comment: @KubaDo You need to learn how to isolate the problems and how to debug your code. It's working well in an isolated [MCVE]. I'll add the full code to the answer.

Comment: Thank You very much, Your code is not working as expected with LIKE operator, i have managed expected result with DataView class

Comment: When the only change that you need in the answer is changing `=` to `LIKE` (which was originally suggested the the comment) I'd say it means the answer is working.